# Problem using R by shell - But the same script works at RStudio

Tags: r, shell, unix

I have this script in shell:

```
R -q -e "library(knitr);data<- read.table('dados.txt', header = T);siregid.table<- as.data.frame(table(unlist(data$siregid))); a=data.frame(unclass(summary(siregid.table$Freq)), check.names = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE);a$names<-rownames(a);a$names<-as.character(a$names);b<- a[ , order(names(a))];c <- setNames(data.frame(t(b[,-1])), b[,1]); kable(head(c), format = 'rst', row.names = FALSE);"
```

but this error occurs:

```
Error in order(names(a)) : argument 1 is not a vector
Execution halted
```

but the same script works perfectly when I run at RStudio. What's the matter?

update:
My table `a` in shell (terminal)
[image]

and My table `a`in RStudio:
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207445/discussion-on-question-by-curious-g-problem-using-r-by-shell-but-the-same-scr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the dollar sign. Just this.